# SQL Server: Get sum based on Id from single column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table as

[image]

I need result as

[image]

I only have two CaseNo, 1 and 2.
How can I do this in single query, not common table expression or separate queries?

Comment: A CTE is a single query.

Comment: CTE is single query, but then again you need to select from cte.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select 1 as CaseNo1, sum(case when CaseNo = 1 then Amount end) as Amount1,
       2 as CaseNo2, sum(case when CaseNo = 2 then Amount end) as Amount2
from table;
```

However, I would not recommend doing this transformation in SQL.  If you need the data in this format in an application, you should probably do it in the application layer.

Comment: I was just about to post the same code. I agree. Also, as soon as you get `CaseNo3` things start to get uglier.

Comment: Perfect, I was thinking about some self join. 
Sorry for my limited knowledge.

I am unable to understand why my question is downgraded.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 'Amount' , 
 [1], [2]
FROM
(SELECT CaseNo, Amount
    FROM table) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
sum(Amount)
FOR CaseNo IN ( [1], [2])
) AS PivotTable;
```